# How to write division with circle notation in Latex

Tags: latex

To write division in Latex we can write `\div`, addition with circle we can write `\bigoplus`, and multiplication with circle by `\bigotimes`.

My question is how to write a division with circle around ([image]) notation in Latex? I've tried `\bigodiv` but it doesn't work.

Anyone knows, please help. Thank you!

Comment: You can just insert the Unicode symbol ⨸.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathabx` package provides `\bigodiv`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
    
\[
  \bigodiv
\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I tried \bigodiv and \odiv already but I didn't know the mathabx package. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MinHaw You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I do not get if `big` is wanted or not. If not, each of the two packages [`stix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix) and [`mathabx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) supply the command `\odiv`. The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\[
a \odiv b
\]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: screenshot of output pdf]